# Thymeleaf display list of authors of the book

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm stuck with a problem. I want to display all of the **books** from my database as a list and what is more, for every of them display list of it's **authors**. This is how my controller method looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/new",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newBooks() {
        List<Book> books = bookRepository.findAllByOrderByPremiereDateDesc();
        Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();
        for(Book b:books){
            authors = b.getAuthors();

        }

        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("books",books);
        model.put("authors", authors);

        return new ModelAndView("books/new","model",model);
    }
```

but I have no idea how to *link books with their authors* to display them properly in my view:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Title original</th>
            <th>Premiere date</th>
            <th>Authors</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="b : ${model.books}">
            <td th:text="${b.title}"></td>
            <td th:text="${b.titleOriginal}"></td>
            <td th:text="${b.premiereDate}"></td>
        <tr th:each="a: ${b.authors}">
            <td th:text="${a.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${a.surname}"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Also my **Book (entity) model class**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "book_id")
    private int bookId;
    @Column(name = "isbn")
    private long isbn;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "title_original")
    private String titleOriginal;
    @Column(name = "premiere_date")
    private Date premiereDate;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "book_author", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")})
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<Author>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<table>
    <span th:each="b: ${model.books}">
        <td>
            <tr th:each="a: ${b.authors}">
                <p th:text="${a.name}"></p>
            </tr>
        <td>
    </span>
</table>
```

Try a nested loop!

Comment: What if I would want it to look like: Book1 : author1, author2, author3, etc.. ; Book2: author1, author3, etc.. ?

Comment: Nvm, got it! Thanks for your help mate :)